# Override ng2-file-upload uploader

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop, http-post

I want to use ng2-file-uploader just for the drag and drop functionality. I built my own service and function for upload. I'm trying to understand how the drag and drop functionality works. It seems like:

```
public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

 public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
        this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
    }
```

are the functions that add the file to the queue. Is there a simple way to recreate this drag and drop functionality, or override the uploader?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/40341176/4793153 for drap and drop functionality

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!